# How to introduce a new variable in Coq?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I was wondering if there is a way to introduce an entirely new variable during the proof of a theorem in Coq?

For a complete example, consider the following property [from here](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ebcpierce/sf/current/Prop.html) about the evenness of the length of a list.

```
Inductive ev_list {X:Type}: list X -> Prop :=
  | el_nil : ev_list []
  | el_cc  : forall x y l, ev_list l -> ev_list (x :: y :: l).
```

Now I want to prove that for any list `l` if its `length` is even, then `ev_list l` holds:

```
Lemma ev_length__ev_list': forall X (l : list X), ev (length l) -> ev_list l.
Proof.
  intros X l H.
```

which gives:

```
1 subgoals
X : Type
l : list X
H : ev (length l)
______________________________________(1/1)
ev_list l
```

Now, I'd like to "define" a new free variable `n` and a hypothesis `n = length l`. In hand-written math, I think we can do this, and then do induction about `n`. But is there a way to do the same in Coq?

Note. the reasons I ask are that:

1. I don't want to introduce this `n` artificially into the statement of the theorem itself, as is done in the page linked earlier, which IMHO is unnatural.
2. I tried to `induction H.`, but it seems not working. Coq wasn't able to do case analysis on `length l`'s `ev`-ness, and no induction hypothesis (IH) was generated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a common issue in Coq proofs. You can use the `remember` tactic:

```
remember (length l) as n.
```

If you're doing induction on `H` as well, you might also have to generalize over `l` beforehand, by doing

```
generalize dependent l.
induction H.
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the Curry-Howard Isomorphism, hypothesis in your context are just variables. You can define new variables with a function. The following `refine` tactic extends the goal with a fresh variable `n` (that is set to `length l`) and a proof `e` that `n = length l` (that is set to `eq_refl`).

```
Lemma ev_length__ev_list': forall X (l : list X), ev (length l) -> ev_list l.
Proof.
  intros X l H.
  refine ((fun n (e:n = length l) => _) (length l) eq_refl).
  (* proof *)
Admitted.
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a new variable only for your induction, you can use directly

```
induction (length l) eqn:H0
```